# Naming based on value counts

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I want to name the values of a column which have a frequency of less than `35` as `'OTHERS'` in python3.

For example,if i say `df.column_valuecounts()`, I get the different valuecounts,

```
CA 45

TE 56

FL 4

NC 8
```

I've tried the following code which some somewhat fixed the problem:

```
df.STATE[~df.STATE.isin(df.STATE.value_counts().index[:35])] = 'Other'
```

But I want my results as follows:

```
CA 45

TE 56

FL OTHERS

NC OTHERS
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use

```
df.val = df.loc[:, 'val'].apply(lambda x: 'OTHERS' if x<35 else x)
```

where `state` and `val` are the column names.

The `val` column is selected using `loc` and then `apply()` is used with the help of a lambda function.